Postman gives wrong number of arguments
Postman says number of procedure parameters is 4 when I am passing 3 values. Which is higher than procedure parameters in database 3. There is a mismatch in parameters in query call statement and parameters as shown in postman. How does postman calculate number of parameters in query?
Controller
@PostMapping("/Insemp")

public String InsertEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
    String ename = employee.getName();
    String department = employee.getDepartment();
    Double salary = employee.getSalary();
    return employeeService.InsertEmployee(ename,department,salary);
}

Repository:
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {
  
    @Procedure(name = "InsertEmployee")
    String InsertEmployee(@Param("ename") String ename, @Param("department") String department, @Param("salary") Double salary);

}

Service function:
public String InsertEmployee(String ename, String department, Double salary) {
    employeeRepository.InsertEmployee(ename,department,salary);
    return "Successfully added";
}

Model class:
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Employee {

    // Declaring fields with annotations
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String department;
    private double salary;
}

// and getters and setters.

Stored procedure in mysql workbench:
delimiter \\

CREATE PROCEDURE InsertEmployee (IN ename VARCHAR(100), IN department VARCHAR(100), IN salary DOUBLE)

BEGIN

INSERT INTO employee (name,department,salary) VALUES (ename,department,salary);

END \\

delimiter ;

Error in postman:
{
    "timestamp": "2024-11-07T06:16:10.389+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "trace": "org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not prepare statement [Number of procedure parameters in the query (4) is higher than the number of procedure parameters in the database (3)] [{call InsertEmployee(?,?,?,?)}]\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:341)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:241)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:550)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:335)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:160)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:136)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:223)\r\n\tat jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy121.InsertEmployee(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat com.femtosptestone.femtosptestone.service.EmployeeService.InsertEmployee(EmployeeService.java:34)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:355)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:768)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:379)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:768)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:720)\r\n\tat com.femtosptestone.femtosptestone.service.EmployeeService$$SpringCGLIB$$0.InsertEmployee(<generated>)\r\n\tat com.femtosptestone.femtosptestone.controller.EmployeeController.InsertEmployee(EmployeeController.java:37)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:255)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:188)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:926)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:831)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914)\r\n\tat jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)\r\n\tat jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:195)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:483)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:384)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:905)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)\r\nCaused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement [Number of procedure parameters in the query (4) is higher than the number of procedure parameters in the database (3)] [{call InsertEmployee(?,?,?,?)}]\r\n\tat org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:63)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:108)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:194)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:85)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.buildOutputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:658)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.getOutputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:607)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.outputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:860)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.execute(ProcedureCallImpl.java:844)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$ProcedureExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:345)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:92)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:152)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:140)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:170)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:158)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:169)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:148)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:70)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:379)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:138)\r\n\t... 71 more\r\nCaused by: java.sql.SQLException: Number of procedure parameters in the query (4) is higher than the number of procedure parameters in the database (3)\r\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:130)\r\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:98)\r\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:90)\r\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:64)\r\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.CallableStatement.generateParameterMap(CallableStatement.java:539)\r\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.CallableStatement.<init>(CallableStatement.java:594)\r\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.CallableStatement.getInstance(CallableStatement.java:482)\r\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.parseCallableStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:1458)\r\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareCall(ConnectionImpl.java:1482)\r\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareCall(ConnectionImpl.java:1473)\r\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareCall(ProxyConnection.java:307)\r\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareCall(HikariProxyConnection.java)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$1.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:93)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:183)\r\n\t... 91 more\r\n",
    "message": "could not prepare statement [Number of procedure parameters in the query (4) is higher than the number of procedure parameters in the database (3)] [{call InsertEmployee(?,?,?,?)}]",
    "path": "/api/Insemp"
}

I could not get answers from google or chatgpt for this. Please kindly explain the answers thoroughly such that a new programmer can understand the answer.
If you see I am passing query       employeeRepository.InsertEmployee(ename,department,salary);
which has 3 paramteres. But postman says [Number of procedure parameters in the query (4) is higher than the number of procedure parameters in the database (3)]
I initially thought id generated value was the fourth parameter. So I added it to query. employeeRepository.InsertEmployee(id,ename,department,salary); which has 4 parameters. But postman says [Number of procedure parameters in the query (5)].
The number of parameters is always shown as one extra from what is passed in the query.
I tried passing 2 parameters name and department. But postman says [Number of procedure parameters in the query (3) is higher than the  number of procedure parameters in the database (2)]

You should copy and paste console log to the question, or share a GitHub repository.

"trace": "org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not prepare statement etc... is the console log. It is coming in one line. I dk why

Is the console ok now?

If you use an ORM, then why do you create a separate stored procedure to insert rows into your table?

It was given to me as a task to learn insert stored procedure in spring boot

The fourth parameter is the return result of the call. Specifically, this line:
String InsertEmployee(@Param("ename") String ename, @Param("department") String department, @Param("salary") Double salary);

Because you are returning a String, it is treating it like an out parameter. You will either need to modify your procedure to have an output parameter or just change the method to void like the following:
@Procedure(name = "InsertEmployee")
void InsertEmployee(@Param("ename") String ename, @Param("department") String department, @Param("salary") Double salary);


Tks for the answer. Works like a charm
